# Show that $(X,d)$ is complete if and only if $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I have been trying to answer this question and came up with this. I am not sure if all the assumptions that I made are correct. Also is my use of cauchy sequences correct? Does my proof look alright?

I would really appreciate any insight\advice you can offer

**Question**

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Define $\overline{d} : X \times X \rightarrow R$ by $\overline{d}(x,y) = min\{d(x,y) ,1\}$.

Show that $(X,d)$ is complete if and only if $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete

**My proof attempt**

*forward*

Let $(X,d)$ is complete. Then for all cauchy sequences $\{x_n\}$ in $(X,d)$, $x_n \rightarrow p \in X$.

There exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for $n,m \geq n_0$

$\overline{d}(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$

thus $x_n \rightarrow p $ converges in $(X,\overline{d})$, thus $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete

*backward*

Let $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete. Then for all cauchy sequences $\{x_n\}$ in $(X,\overline{d})$, $x_n \rightarrow p \in X$

There exists  $\epsilon > 0$  s.t  $ \overline{d}(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for $ n,m \geq n_0$

For $n_0 \geq 1$, $d(x_n,x_m)= \overline{d}(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$

thus $x_n \rightarrow p $ converges in $(X,d)$, thus $(X,d)$ is complete

**This concludes my attempted proof**

Comment: For the forward direction you have to start with a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\overline{d})$, not in $(X,d)$. Similarly, for the backward direction, you have to start with a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$.

Comment: In *backward*, I guess you mean $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ instead of $\varepsilon <0$... Moreover, you just proved in both case that being a Cauchy sequence in one metric, you have a Cauchy sequence in the other one, not that it converges...

Comment: @Surb doesn't $\overline{d}(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for forward and $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for  backward prove that cauchy sequences in both metric spaces converge?

Comment: @MartinR do I just flip the forward and backward arguments around?

Comment: No. – Note also that a proof for convergence always means that you show something for *all* $\epsilon > 0$, it never suffices to say “there exists an $\epsilon > 0$.”

Comment: @MartinR ok, thank you , let me see if I can rework this

Comment: Do not ask the same question repeatedly. You got an answer:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4440234. You should delete the above question.