# Show that $(X,d)$ is complete if and only if $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete (Part 2)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I reworked my proof that I attempted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439974/show-that-x-d-is-complete-if-and-only-if-x-overlined-is-complete)

I used subsequences to prove it. I am not 100% sure that it is worded correctly.

I would really appreciate it if you could offer any insight/advice that you can offer, and thank you for those who helped me in my previous attempt.

**Question**

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Define $\overline{d} : X \times X \rightarrow R$ by $\overline{d}(x,y) = min\{d(x,y) ,1\}$.

Show that $(X,d)$ is complete if and only if $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete

**My second proof attempt**

*forward*

Assume that $(X,d)$ is complete. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\overline{d})$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow p$.

Let $\{x_{n_k}\}$ be a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ consisting of the tail end where $n_k >N$ s.t $n,m \geq N$, $ \ \overline{d}(x_n,x_m) < 1$

thus $\forall \epsilon > 0$ , $d(x_{n_i},x_{n_l}) = \overline{d}(x_{n_i},x_{n_l}) < \epsilon$ for all $n_i, n_l\in \mathbb{N}$

thus as $x_n \rightarrow p$ so does $x_{n_k} \rightarrow p$

as $(X,d)$ is complete, $p \in X$

thus $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete

*backward*

Let $(X,\overline{d})$ be complete. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow p$.

thus $\forall \epsilon >0, \overline{d}(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$

thus $x_n \rightarrow p$ converges in $(X,\overline{d})$

as $(X,\overline{d})$ is complete, $p\in X$

thus $(X,d)$ is also complete

**This concludes my proof attempt**

Comment: What do you mean by $x_n \to p$? You assumed one metric to be Cauchy. In the other metric the sequence may not converge.

Comment: @温泽海 I am not sure which $x_n \rightarrow p$ you are referring to. For the *backward* proof, dosen't  $\forall \epsilon >0, \overline{d}(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ make it converge?

Comment: I am referring to both. In the forward for instance, you wrote "Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\overline{d})$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow p$". $\{x_n\}$ may not converge in $(X,\overline{d})$ a priori

Comment: @温泽海 I assumed that if $d(x_{n_i},x_{n_l}) = \overline{d}(x_{n_i},x_{n_l})$ and that $x_{n_k}$ are terms of $X$ then they both shrink down to $0$ then they both should converge to the same point

Comment: Then you should make that clearer. Given the way it is written no one can understand it.

Comment: Are you sure this statement is correct? For example, if $\epsilon =2$, $\overline{d}(x_m,x_n)=\min\{d(x_m,x_n),1 \} \leq 2$ allows to $d(x_m,x_n)$ to be large. Therefore, $\{x_n\}$ may not be a Cauchy sequence $(X,{d}).$

Comment: @Ilovemath from what I understand of Cauchy sequences as long as you have $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon,  \forall \epsilon >0 $ then we have a Cauchy sequence, regardless how the start of the sequence looks like just that the end(tail) of the sequence is important to converge

Comment: You need to show that a sequence is Cauchy with $d$ **iff** it is Cauchy with $\bar{d}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has the right idea, but it must be improved.

1. "Assume that $(X,d)$ is complete. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\overline{d})$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow p$." It does not make sense to assume $x_n \to p$. You have to take any Cauchy sequence in $(X,\overline{d})$ and to **show** that it converges to some $p \in X$.
   So let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\{x_n\}$is Cauchy with respect to $\bar d$, we find $N$ such that $\bar d (x_n,x_m) < \min(1,\epsilon)$ for $n,m \ge N$. But then $d(x_n,x_m) = \bar d(x_n,x_m)$ for $n,m \ge N$, thus $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for $n,m \ge N$. This shows that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $(X,d)$ and converges to some $p  \in X$ by completeness. This means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $\bar d(x_n,p) \le d(x_n,p) < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$. Thus $x_n \to p$ with respect to $\bar d$.
2. "Let $(X,\overline{d})$ be complete. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow p$." You made the same mistake as above. Actually you have to take any Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$ and to **show** that it converges to some $p \in X$.
   We have $\bar d(x,y) \le d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$, thus each Cauchy sequence with respect to $d$ is also one with respect to $\bar d$, thus by completeness $\{x_n\}$ converges to some $p \in X$ with respect to $\bar d$. This means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $\bar d(x_n,p)  < \min(1,\epsilon)$ for $n \ge N$. But then $d(x_n, p) = \bar d(x_n,p) < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$ which shows that $x_n \to p$ with respect to $d$.

Comment: Thank you, now I believe I understand. First I must take any Cauchy sequence, as by definition: a metric space is complete if all Cauchy sequence converge to a point in $X$. I believe that I wrongfully assumed that all Cauchy sequences converge. Then I can remove the whole subsequence by simply restricting our attention to when the metric is $<min\{1,\epsilon \}$